# How to check a data.table key works properly and why it would not?

Tags: r, encoding, data.table

Not sure a bug or my fault - a `data.table` key is not working for the table, I read from UTF-encoded file( [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ghu3koncpnb8dir/boys_ru.txt) ).

```
names <- data.table(name = unique(read.table(file = "boys_ru.txt", header = FALSE, sep = "\n", quote = "", stringsAsFactors = F)$V1), sex = 1)
setkey(names, name)
```

`data.table` doesn't seem to recognize the key properly. `names["сергей"]` returns nothing while  `names[name == "сергей"]`works fine

```
> names[name == "сергей"]
     name sex
1: сергей   1
```

If I create the table myself, everything works fine too

```
dt1 <- data.table(name = rep("сергей", 5), sex = rep(1, 5))
setkey(dt1, name)
```

I don't know what to do, cause this doesn't allow me to join this table with another 10M rows table on name field. Interestingly, `merge.data.frame` works as expected with `names` table (but way too slow). `sessionInfo` -

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=C            LC_COLLATE=C         LC_MONETARY=C        LC_MESSAGES=C       
 [7] LC_PAPER=C           LC_NAME=C            LC_ADDRESS=C         LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=C     LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
```

Comment: Check [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5295&group_id=240&atid=5335). Also follow the links to FR#5266 and FR#5159 in that post. For now, as long as the same strings are of same encodings between the two data.tables, you'll have no issues with the join. Check the encoding of the string with which you've a problem to see if they're of identical encodings on both tables. This'll eventually be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have been more careful when loading the file, adding explicitly `read.table(..., encoding = "UTF-8"`).  Otherwise the column gets wrong encoding, making `data.table` unable to match columns of different encodings.
Thanks to @Arun and participants of the RForge discussion above for pointing to the solution.